# Package database file on solaris 10

Tags: package-management, solaris

I am looking for the file that represents the solaris 10 package database - if there is such thing. The reason is that I want to be able to efficiently compute a checksum that represents the current patch level (including any third party packages), so that after a possible rollback I can "prove" the rollback was a success (e.g. rolling back using zfs snapshots). So I tough the package database where `pkginfo` gets its data from would be a natural choice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solaris 10 uses `/var/sadm/pkg` and `/var/sadm/patch` to track package and patch versions.  It does not use a database like RPM does.  If you are using ZFS snapshots as a way to rollback from patches, try checking the contents of `/var/sadm/patch` before patching, post patching, and post rollback.

If you are not already using the feature, investigate Alternate Boot Environments for Solaris especially since you are already using ZFS.  [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/solaris-live-upgrade-wp-167900.pdf) is a whitepaper to get you started.  You create your ABE, patch it, activate it, and reboot.  If things don't work, activate the previous boot environment, activate it, and reboot again.  It's a great feature of Solaris.

With this methodology, you have an explicit copy (or zfs snapshot/clone) that you apply patches to, so there is a clear delineation between the pre and post patching environments for your validation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow what you need, but the file you're looking for is most likely /var/sadm/install/contents.

And as MikeA noted, maybe you want to look at using ABEs if you're not already doing so--it works quite well and efficiently at patching and maintaining the system and even more so if you're using ZFS.